# onclick event on jqm listview not working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, phonegap-plugins

In my Phonegap android application dynamically adding list items to jqm listview where on click on a item ,am taking the item index and passing it to another page to display relative info based on clicked item.It was working fine with jqm v1.0a3 but now i updated to jqm v1.1.0   and now onclick event is not working.Any help?

```
for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++)
{
 var li=document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML="<a onclick='getIndexOfClickedListItem("+i+");'></a><p><b>CustName</b>"+result[i].fields.NAME+</p>";
 ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiya Please take a look in here (Since I cannot see your full code)  **working demo using JQM list view** http://jsfiddle.net/3RyXz/

This will add new li as well you can navigate between pages.

This should help, please let me know if I missing anything.

> **Updated Demo**

here with index alert http://jsfiddle.net/RTpqd/14/ (I have added the similar function as you need - `getIndexOfClickedListItem` :)

Behavior: 1st - click on `Add Item` link and then click on the `foo1` `li` you will see the correct index value popping up.

**code**

```
$('.add').click( function(){
    $('#1, #2').append('<li><a onclick="getIndexOfClickedListItem('+count+');"> foo' + count + '</a></li>');

    $(this).closest('.ui-content').find('.ui-listview').listview('refresh');

    count++;
});
```

**getIndexOfClickedListItem function here** rest demo will make more clear

```
//adding click on new list item for index
function getIndexOfClickedListItem(str){

     alert("The clicked list index is ==>" + str);
}
```

**part of code which does add li**

```
$('.add').click( function(){
    $('#1, #2').append('<li>' + count + '</li>');

    $(this).closest('.ui-content').find('.ui-listview').listview('refresh');

    count++;
});
```

Comment: Thanx for your quick response.Dynamically item addition is working fine but i wanted to get the index of the clicked item of a listView.

Comment: @Tarak aha see here: much cleaner and I will update my post as well about how to use: http://jsfiddle.net/RTpqd/14/

Comment: thanks its working now.But still wonder why onclick does not work with jqm 1.1.0 but works fine with 1.0a.

Answer (score 2):

```
      var items=new Array();          
      for(i=0;i<data.resulrset.length-1;i++)
      {
         items.push("<li onclick='getvalue(\""+data.resulrset[i].city_name+"\")'><a href='#'>"+ data.resulrset[i].city_name + "</a></li>")              
      }
      var liinner_html=items.join('');      
      $("#list").html(liinner_html);
      $(list).show();
```